# Helping identifying a common mode choke

Tags: inductor, common-mode-choke

Seeking help to identify the following common mode choke. The best guess is it a part from [Sumida Corporation.](https://www.sumida.com/)

[image]

This part is from a refrigerator.

Any of the following information is greatly appreciated

- Datasheet
- Manufacture
- Specification

Based on research it was assumed that following part might have similar specification. Currently not too sure.

- [SU9HD-40006](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/kemet/SU9HD-40006/10321623) from Kemet

Following are results form searches.

- [Results from google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=UU10.5-31%20choke%20common%20mode&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS892US892&ei=wsR7X_rqL6KyytMP1_6AiA8&start=20&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj609T45J7sAhUimXIEHVc_APE4ChDy0wN6BQgLEIQC&biw=1536&bih=754)
- [Results from Digikey search](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/common-mode-chokes/839?s=N4IgTCBcDaIKpwIwAYQF0C%2BQ)
- [PZ-UU10.5-Series 0.5~50mH Common Mode Choke Line Filter Common Mode Inductor](http://www.dgpinzhan.com/sale-7730505-pz-uu10-5-series-0-5-50mh-common-mode-choke-line-filter-common-mode-inductor.html)
- [UU Series Common Mode Choke](https://www.digikey.com/catalog/en/partgroup/uu-series/41606)s

Comment: Where did it come from?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  cuui dorm room refrigerator

Comment: Yes looks like a 31 mH line choke. Why?  Kemet source looks ok

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Trying to suppress noise from a wall wart. Randomly placed this part, and it appears to work. Thus trying to work backward to confirm the solution.

Comment: Wall supply is regulated? Causing noise ? To what?  Yes a Pi filter or CLC with CM L choke will attenuate SMPS noise, but it ought to have one, maybe too cheap to...

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, The Kemet part we used is 5.95 µH. Looks like it is too small.

Comment: Yes uH is too low impedance for 30kHz region noise use load R/L = 2pi omega and C impedance shunt with plastic line rated caps to compute impedance ratio attenuation... +1nF

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, Curious, how did you determine it is 30kHz noise load. Also can you help me understand why "plastic line rated capacitors".  Also I have ordered 10mH and 2.2 mH inductors.

Comment: Line caps are for L-L or L-G as X or Y rated for transient safety Poly type caps.  Just a guestimate on SMPS f commonly used above audio range.

Comment: 2 way line filters for SMPS to block line noise in and switcher noise out use a CM choke to make CM rejection of carrier and differential mode with cap So we call it a CLC CM Pi filter common to most SMPS line inputs.  XY info https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/333029/what-is-an-xy-rated-safety-capacitor-exactly  The the CM choke or Balun equalizes high impedance on L-N then the caps are chosen to shunt at low Z(f) by impedance ratio yet minimize leakage to gnd < 0.5mA at 50,60 Hz

Comment: This shows it better for both CM and DM noise rejection https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201302/switch-mode-power-supply-and-emi-on-input-power-line-filtering except this is a DC source with large caps , so AC source uses 1~4nF for same benefits of attenuation of differential and common mode noise , read Murata link p30

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thank you for you insights.